# Lambda expression, from Python to C#

Tags: c#, python, dictionary, lambda

I am trying to rewrite some thing from python to c#, I have managed to recreate the dictionaries I but I am having trouble understanding the dictionary comprehension in c#.
here is the python code I would like to recreate in c#

```
distances={1:.02,30:.001,1000:.001}
minSearch=(min(distances.items(), key=lambda x:x[1]))
```

this is the dictionary I have in c#

```
Dictionary<int, double> distDict = new Dictionary<int, double>();
```

Thanks for the answer here it is implemented

```
                List<MapPoint> list = new List<MapPoint>();
                list.Add(pointDict[Convert.ToInt32(startOid)]);
                while (pointDict.Count()>1)
                {
                    var shape = pointDict[Convert.ToInt32(startOid)];
                    pointDict.Remove(Convert.ToInt32(startOid));
                    var X = shape.X;
                    var Y = shape.Y;
                    var Z = shape.Z;
                    foreach(KeyValuePair<int,MapPoint> point in pointDict)
                    {
                        var X2 = point.Value.X;
                        var Y2 = point.Value.Y;
                        var Z2 = point.Value.Z;
                        var squaredZDist = Math.Pow((Z - Z2), 2);
                        var squaredDist = Math.Pow(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(X - X2, 2) + Math.Pow(Y - Y2, 2)),2);
                        var threeDSquaredDist = Math.Sqrt(squaredDist + squaredZDist);
                        distDict[point.Key] = threeDSquaredDist;
                    }
                    var minValue = distDict.Min(x => x.Value);
                    var minPair = distDict
                                    .Where(x => x.Value == minValue)
                                    .First();
                    startOid = minPair.Key;
                    list.Add(pointDict[minPair.Key]);

                    distDict.Clear();
                }
                Polyline polyline = PolylineBuilder.CreatePolyline(list);
                var pipeLayer = mapView.Map.Layers.OfType<FeatureLayer>()
                                                    .Where(x=>x.Name == "PIPELINE")
                                                    .First();
                MessageBox.Show(pipeLayer.Name.ToString());
                var createFeatures = new EditOperation();
                createFeatures.Name = "Create Polyline";
                createFeatures.Create(pipeLayer, polyline);
                createFeatures.Execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can duplicate that python using:

```
var distDict = new Dictionary<int, double> {
  {1,.02},{30,.001},{1000,.001}
};
var minValue = distDict.Min(x => x.Value);
var minPair = distDict
                .Where(x => x.Value == minValue)
                .First();
var expected = new KeyValuePair<int, double>(30, .001);
Assert.Equal(expected, minPair);
```

Comment: The answer worked perfectly. Thank you very much. I posted the implementation above in the question.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with:

```
KeyValuePair<int, double> minSearch = distDict.OrderBy(x => x.Value).First()
```

This is thus a `KeyValuePair<int, double>` that contains a `Key` and `Value` property of the dictionary entry with the smallest `Value` in the `Dictionary.

C# will not order the collection immediately with `.OrderBy(..)`, but construct an [**`OrderedEnumerable`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/f3b56d1dfc2b8fb52c8d22a3bcd32a797b684adf/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/OrderedEnumerable.cs#L10). This will normally result in the fact that the `.First()` will aim to calculate the smallest item in *linear* time, so *O(n)*, and like @flakes says, constant memory complexity *O(1)*.

Comment: Cool! I never knew that about `OrderedEnumerable`. I always assumed that `OrderBy` does a complete sort.

Comment: @flakes: well of course if you enumerate over the items, it eventually performs a full sort, but `.First()` should normally work in linear time.

Comment: And `O(1)` for memory complexity is also super nice.